# Unable to view Image in browser from public/assets folder in Next.js

Tags: reactjs, web, next.js, nextjs-image, next-images

My Code is as follows:

```
import Image from "next/image";
import React from "react";
import { ProcessImg } from "../public/assets/process_img.png";
```

```
          <Image
            className="lg:w-3/5 md:w-1/2 object-cover object-center rounded-lg md:mt-0 mt-12"
            src={ProcessImg}
            height={100}
            width={100}
            alt="step"
          />
```

The alternative text is only visible on
The screenshot of output is as follows:
https://freeimage.host/i/mEBJiN

I tried changing extension of image. I tried changing src of Image. I was expecting to get image displayed in browser.

Answer (score 1):

Try to import image as below:

```
import ProcessImg from "../public/assets/process_img.png";
```